# How to colour only words in multiline block element?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I am trying to achieve, that only the text inside a multiline headline element has a background colour with gaps between the lines.

My current solution is to wrap every word in a span but sadly it only works properly in Firefox and Chrome.

This is my current HTML markup:

```
<div>
  <h3>
    <span>This</span>
    <span>is</span>
    <span>some</span>
    <span>interesting</span>
    <span>Text</span>
    <span>without</span>
    <span>any</span>
    <span>meaning.</span>
  </h3>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
div {
background: black;
height: 200px;
 width:  300px;
position: relative;    
}

h3 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 0;
    right: 20%;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 20px;
}

span {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: black;
    background: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 2px 6px 2px 0;
}
​
```

Please have a look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ez92s/

If you look at it in Opera and Safari, the words have little gap between them and in IE10 the words are all in one line.

How can I achieve the look it has in Chrome in any browser (IE10+)?

Much thanks in advance, McFarlane

Comment: @SimonPertersen: Your solution kills the gap between the lines I wanted and it doesn't display properly in Safari and IE10. Did you even try it?

Answer (score 2):

i think u need to remove span after every single word put whole text in single span and use word-spacing property for example `span{ word-spacing:10px;}`  and if u don't want to remove span you can use margin instead of padding

Comment: thanks. one span works as expected on every browser. I've updated my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ez92s/4/
Now how can I add some more space behind the last word of a line so the background does not stop instantly?

Comment: you mean you want to add some space at the end of the line with white background? if yes just add padding.

Answer (score 0):

Change `padding` to `margin`

```
span {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: black;
    background: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 2px 6px 2px 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ez92s/1/

Padding retains the background colour margin does not.

Comment: That is exactly what I do NOT want to achieve. See my post: Chrome and FF do what I want. And both of them do not display gaps.

Comment: Maybe explain it a bit better? I notice I'm not the only one to come to this conclusion (shrug).

Answer (score 0):

Add a margin to the span to give the spans spacing between them:

```
margin-right:1px;
```

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ez92s/2/)

Comment: I do NOT want gaps between the words. Only between the lines.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for Opera or Safari, but IE seems to respond to adding `display: inline-block;` to your span definition.